# How to add relations to a custom field in laravel nova?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, one-to-many, laravel-nova

I am trying to make a custom field that creates and attach one-to-many relations to the model, but I can't figure out how to do this, I don't know how to pass the data to the formData object from FormField.vue.

I don't know which name would accept the field to create the relationship nor I have found anything on the web about it. I tried to put the name of the hasMany function of the model but Laravel doesn't accept it:

This is the parent's model hasMany function:

```
public function serveis() {
    return $this->hasMany(ServeiPersonalitzat::class);
}
```

This is the custom field call inside the resource fields:

```
Servei::make("Serveis", "serveis")
```

I get this error when creating the resource:

```
"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'serveis' in 'field list' (Connection: mysql, SQL: insert into `pressuposts` (`impost_id`, `total`, `created_at`, `data_final`, `serveis`, `updated_at`) values (1, 123, 2023-07-06 00:00:00, 2023-08-05 00:00:00, [{\"tipus_id\":1,\"nom\":\"123\",\"descripcio\":\"123\",\"subtotal\":132}], 2023-07-06 10:42:00))"
```

I got the previous error every time the field name wasn't one of the model's attributes, so I don't even know if another name apart from the fields' could be used.

I expect to find a way to create a child model and bind it to the parent from a custom tool. I think the solution might be to find the correct field name.

Comment: This is not a solution center. We will help you to narrow don your problem. Please show your efforts (code) so we can see what is wrong or missing.